# how to use xml layout as cluster marker Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-studio, android-maps-utils

I have a question, Is it possible to set a layout with multi imageviews and textviews as a cluster marker on the google map by android map utils? and how? if somebody provide an good example it would be great this an example of what i want to do:

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way than what I used that was a year a go this method takes a lot of time if the data set is big so use it on small data set or talk to the designer for other options.

you can create a layout with what you want the get the bitmap of this layout this add the bitmap as a marker to the map since add marker only takes images.
*you need to set the data before creating the bitmap

first step inflate and set data to your layout

```
View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null);
```

second get the bitmap from this view

```
Bitmap bitmap = createDrawableFromView(
                                getActivity(), marker);
```

third add the bitmap as a marker

```
   MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(
                                    new LatLng(lat, lng))
                                    // .title(address)
                                    .snippet(i + "")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                            Marker customMarker = googleMap.addMarker(mo);
```

this is how to get the bitmap

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    if (context != null) {
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

goodluck with that it was a lot of pain.

Comment: thanks i'm going to give it a try, this code is for single marker not cluster but i try to implement inside my codes, but one more question i should set data before use createDrawableFromView, and also is that possible to use this inside the onBeforeClusterRendered constructor?

Comment: yes you must set all data before you create the bitmap
if there is an url image load it first an then create the marker i didn't use onBeforeClusterRendered so I don't know give it a try.